# Poisson Process with 2 variables.

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> A Poisson process has a mean rate of $10$ orders per second. The orders could be from type $A$ with a probability of $0.7$ or from type $B$ with a probability of $0.3$. Orders are independent of each other. Consider a $3$ second time interval.
>
> 1. What is the probability that we have $5$ orders of type $A$?
> 2. What is the probability that we have $5$ orders of type $B$?

Should I use a different $\lambda$ when I'm calculating each kind of order?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. Let $0<p<1$ and consider the split processes $\{N_p(t):t\geqslant0\}$ and $\{N_{1-p}(t):t\geqslant0\}$ corresponding to orders from type A and type B, respectively. Let $T>0$ be fixed.

We can think of $N_p$ as $N_p(t) = N(t)B$ where $B\sim\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ is independent of $\{N(t):t\geqslant 0\}$, and similarly $N_{1-p}(t) = N(t)(1-B)$.

Because the split processes are independent with rates $\lambda p$ and $\lambda (1-p)$ (this is a nontrivial fact that you should prove on your own), we have that the probability of $k$ type $A$ orders in $[0,T]$ is

$$
\mathbb P(N_p(T) = k) = e^{-\lambda pT}\frac{(\lambda p T)^k}{k!}
$$

and similarly the probability of $k$ type $B$ orders in $[0,T]$ is 
$$
\mathbb P(N_{1-p}(T) = k) = e^{-\lambda (1-p)T}\frac{(\lambda (1-p) T)^k}{k!}
$$

Plug in $p=\frac7{10}$, $k=5$, $\lambda = 10$, and $T=3$ for your specific problem.

Comment: I was thinking that the value of probability is kinda low in this problem. So I wasn't sure if my answer is right.

Comment: You could always run a simulation to see if you get similar results. In this case you'd just want to generate exponential jump times of the appropriate parameter over the appropriate time interval many times (say, at least 1000), and see how many times there are exactly $5$ orders of type B.